# How to create a drop down button in Python when creating a GUI and extract the selection each time and use it assign it to a variable?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, drop-down-menu

I have to create a GUI which has a drop down button where you can select a currency from the given options and the selection is assigned to a variable called currency which is used in another function. I have written the code below which produces the drop down button but when I make a selection does not reflect it. I am entirely new user of tkinter so I am really not sure where I am going wrong.:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window():
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.grid()
        self.currency= self.select_currency()
        print(self.currency)

    def select_currency(self):
        currencies=sorted(['EUR','GBP','USD'])
        variable=StringVar(root)
        variable.set('GBP')
        option=OptionMenu(root,variable,*currencies)
        option.grid(row=0,column=1)
        name_label=Label(root,text='Currency')
        name_label.grid(row=0,column=0)
        return variable

root=Tk()
window=Window(root)
root.mainloop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would you like it to do? Should it call some function once a currency is selected? You could do the following:
`option = OptionMenu(root,variable,*currencies, command = some_function)`

Comment: No I need it to store the selection each time in self.currency but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why it needs to be stored? you could also use `self.currency.get()` to get the value of the currency when you actually need it, say when you for example press an "Enter" button

Comment: thanks very much this solves my problem, i thought i need to store it each time to use it when i need it.